# RDS storage autoscaling support using terraform for live databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

AWS has [recently](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/rds-storage-auto-scaling/) launched support for storage autoscaling of RDS instances. We have multiple RDS instances with over provisioned storage in our production environment. We want to utilise this new feature to reduce some costs. Since we cannot reduce the storage of a live RDS instance, we will have to first create a RDS instance with less storage with autoscaling support and then migrate the existing data to new instance and then delete the old instance.

We use terraform with the terraform-aws-provider to create our infrastructure. Problem is that I am not able to achieve the above strategy using terraform. 
Here is what i have tried :

1. Modify the existing RDS creation script to create two more
   resources.
2. One is of type `aws_db_snapshot` and other is
   `aws_db_instance` (using the snapshot).
3. However I get the following
   error error modifying DB Instance (test-rds-snapshot):
   InvalidParameterCombination: Invalid storage size for engine name
   postgres and storage type gp2: 20.

```
# Existing RDS instance with over provisioned storage
resource "aws_db_instance" "test_rds"{
.
.
.
}

# My changes below
# The snapshot
resource "aws_db_snapshot" "test_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = "${aws_db_instance.test_rds.id}"
  db_snapshot_identifier = "poc-snapshot"
}

# New instance with autoscale support and reduced storage
resource "aws_db_instance" "test_rds_snapshot" {
  identifier            = "test-rds-snapshot"
  allocated_storage     = 20
  max_allocated_storage = 50
  snapshot_identifier   = "${aws_db_snapshot.test_snapshot.id}"
.
.
.
}
```

I want to know if I am on the right track or not and will I be able to migrate production databases using this strategy. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Turns out that you cannot create a RDS instance with less storage than the snapshot. Since the `test_rds_snapshot` was created by providing a `snapshot_identifier` , the `allocated_storage` parameter was causing the issue. The weird part was that the RDS instance with storage capacity same as that of original one was indeed created in AWS but terraform has thrown an error.